# Scale by values other than count for a clustered dataset in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, clustering

I have a dataset that is a lot of sales data points for a customer. I created a clustered visualization via AGOL of this. Part of the visualization is that they label by the sum of the sales amounts tied to each point that is clustered. It makes a confusing visual though. I have points that are larger (more point aggregation) but have smaller sales totals. I can't seem to switch the clustering size to reflect the sum of the sales. Is there any way to do this in AGOL?